# Norms in $H^{-1/2}$, an inequality.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let

$\|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h}:=\inf\{\|\sigma\|_{div,T_h}:\sigma\in H(div,\Omega),\,\mu=\sigma n^K,\textrm{on }\partial K,K\in T_h\}.$

$T_h$ is a partición of $\Omega$ (usual in finite elements), composed of triangles.

$n^K$ is the normal vector over an edge of the triangle $K\in T_h$, pointing outward of $K$. $H(div,\Omega)$ is the set of vectors with components in $L^2(\Omega)$ with divergence in $L^2(\Omega)$ and

$\|\sigma\|_{div,T_h}^2:=\displaystyle\sum_{K\in T_h}(\|\sigma\|_{L^2(K)^2}^2+\|div(\sigma)\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)})$.

It is true the following?

$\displaystyle\sum_{K\in T_h}\|\mu\|_{-1/2,K}^2\leq C \|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h}^2$

Where $C$ is a constant not depending of the number of triangles of $T_h$.

Comment: Something is off with the definition of $\|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h}$. As written, if $u$ is supported in the interior of the triangles forming the partition, then $\|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h} = 0$, because, as written, $\sigma$ is condition only of the boundary of the triangles.

Comment: @VictorZurkowski But that is possible? I mean, exists a function $\sigma$  in $H(div,K)$ such that $0\neq\sigma\cdot n\in H^{-1/2}(\partial K)$ and $\|\sigma\|_{div,K}^2=\|\sigma\|_{0,K}^2+\|div(\sigma)\|^2_{0,K})=0$? I thought was not possible, becouse the unique element in $H(div,K)$ with norm equal to cero is the vector 0.

Comment: If $\|\sigma\|_{div,K}^2=0$ then $\sigma = 0$, that is why if $\mu=0$ on the boundary of the triangles, then, with the definition you wrote (that involves looking at $\mu$ only at the boundary), $\|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h}^2 = 0$. What is missing is either to say that $\mu$ satisfies some differential equation inside the triangles, or term on the right hind side of $\displaystyle\sum_{K\in T_h}\|\mu\|_{-1/2,K}^2\leq C \|\mu\|_{-1/2,T_h}^2$ with some lower Sovolev norm of $\mu$ or some norm of derivatives of $\mu$ in the triangles.